# How to change keyboard layout

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, keyboard

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 to develop my web apps.
The main page consists of text explaining the app and two text fields to give the user the possibility to enter some information:
    
    
Now I start the app on my iPhone and I'm wondering a bit. If I edit the first field then the keyboard will show a button with the caption "Open" in the bottom right corner. If I edit the second field then the keyboard will show a button with the caption "Search" in the bottom right corner.
How can I change that captions and which keyboard layouts are supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not just in iPhone also in Android based on input element’s `type` keyboard will take up different shapes.

You can check out some of the available [text input types here at this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) But remember not all the input types are supported in all the browsers.

Some examples below.

```
// To get search button
<input type="search" name="mySearch">
// to get numbers only
<input type="numbers" name="myNumber">
```

jQuery Mobile documentation has more information on this fields. Check out the [official documentation here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/textinputs/).

Hope that is enough for you to get started.

Comment: The effect appears if you mix type of text and id with search; you only need to place <input type="text" id="text-search"/> - it's very curious.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure the keyboards that popup are related to the html5 input type attribute, no relation to jquery mobile. For example:

```
   <input type="url" />
```

Should return the keyboard with the dedicated .com button

textarea should show return instead of go

email should show the dedicated @ symbol key

Number will return the number keyboard, and so on

Just make sure your target audience browser type supports the html5 input type

Comment: What happened, was the answer then no?

Comment: No, both fields have the type "text" but with different id and name attributes: The first field has id "text-user" and the second field has the id "text-search".

Comment: Looking at the docs http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/forms-all.html , are your form fields along these lines? Setup jsfiddle?

Comment: It seems that the framework applies the id to the type attribute so

    <input type="text" id="text-search"/>

is interpreted like

    <input type="search" id="text-search"/>

Maybe it's a bug of the framework.

Comment: i tried using the jquery mobile demo page on my IOS device, i was not seeing the word search as a caption, can you post a demo link to the page you made?